# NTLM Authentication Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, odata, ntlm, sap-dotnet-connector

I want to retrieve data from a sharepoint server.
I use the sap odata connector, but the problem is that it is a NTLM authentication.

Now I only get an error message: `401 Unauthorized`.

Can I configure the proxy to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. However, if you put the initial HTML file on the SharePoint server, this will take care of authentication